# Why can't boost::shared_ptr dereference a T[]

Tags: arrays, c++11, boost, shared-ptr

I noticed when writing the following code

```
boost::shared_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[5]);
int* deref = *ptr;
```

That `boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*()` requires T to not be an array type.

> `T & operator*() const; // never throws`
>
> **Requirements:** `T` should not be an array type. The stored pointer must not be 0.
>
> **Returns:** a reference to the object pointed to by the stored pointer.
>
> **Throws:** nothing.

The compiler error that is (rightly) produced is viewable [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ecebb5fc8fd637e)

`std::shared_ptr<T>::operator*()` on the other hand makes no such requirement, but `shared_ptr` doesn't seem to be constructible with `T[]` or `T*`

This of course can be remedied by using scoped/shared_array instead of a smart pointer to an array, or if nothing else by using a `std::vector`.

But that doesn't explain why shared_ptr couldn't have an `operator*()` specified to return a `T*` when T is an array.

Can someone shed some light on why `T[]` is handled specially in `boost::shared_ptr`?

Comment: `operator*` would need to always return a reference to the first element of the array, which is useless in general, when you can't apply a pointer arithmetic like `*(ptr + 1)`. returning `T*` out of `T[]` from `operator*` as you suggest, is rather unintuitive

Comment: to clarify this: `shared_ptr<T[]>` stores an array of `T`s, applying `delete[]` to the stored pointer. it doesn't store some `T[]*` as you claim

Comment: @PiotrS. Because `T`=`U[]`, I'd expect the return type (which is `T&`) to be `U[]&` which after decaying would be `T*`, ie.: not a pointer to the first element in the array. But you're right, the smart pointers store a T[] rather than a `T*`, so I'll clarify the question regarding `T[]*`

Comment: `shared_ptr<T[]>` still stores `T*`, but uses `delete[]` instead of `delete`. the double bracket syntax is used only to distinguish between the two

Comment: @PiotrS. That is entirely legitimate and as I'd expect, my question is mainly about providng a `T*` as the return of `operator*()`. Or rather, returning `T[]` which of course would have to be decayed to `T*`.

Comment: `T[]` is an incomplete type itself. it is **not** stored inside `shared_ptr<T[]>` (neither a pointer to `T[]` like `T[]*` or whatever you think it is), why should `operator*` return `T[]` , and why do you think it should decay to pointer?

Comment: As I understand it, `boost::shared_ptr<T[]>` stores a `T*` inside it and `delete[]`s it when needed. If I dereference the `shared_ptr` I expect to get the T* back.

Comment: so you misunderstand what dereferencing stands for